# How to use "Dynamically Generated HTML->Input Elements" after POSTed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

There are lots of inputs in a single page... These inputs are need to be posted to server to generate custom documents. In other words, every each element will be used on serverside.

### Traditionally

#### Every input can have a name. So, at server-side php can get all these inputs by

```
$_POST[nameOfInput]
```

Or

#### Every input tag can be listened by jquery and on change, values can be saved to an array and post to server by ajax later ... so php can get these values as in javascript ... by

```
$.ajax({
  url: baseUrl+"chat.php",
  data: a,
  type: 'post',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
})
```

But in this project i got little bit confused about these method because;

On this page, number of the inputs and number of input types are dynamic. While user fills the input. According to values typed by user,simultaneously, new input elements are generated. So i am able to post these values to server but i dont have any idea about how to use these in a php page.

Comment: I think you will have to use arrays as names and then use `foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)` server side to process them

Comment: For example; User enters '7'. In that moment an input table with 3 columns and '7' rows is generated (Every cell is input element). Do you mean that? I listen this table with jquery and store these inputs in an array onChange ? and post these arrays at the end ?